# my html file in htdocs to open in netbeans ide

Tags: php, html, netbeans

how can i open my project/files in htdocs in netbeans IDE i tried looking for tutorial but there is none..i tried import but when i do it it does not have file to open or i tried open but i did not open as well..

I downloaded netbeans [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) i got the last one with many checks.

i also downloaded [this](https://netbeans.org/projects_tags/sample) but i cant import it as well.

any suggestions are accepted

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?

Are you working with files in a GIT, Locally or files located on a webserver?

Comment: local files from xammp i made..it is in htdocs so i can run it on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO to

`File>New Project>PHP>PHP Application With Existing Sources.`

The browse to htdocs and select your project folder.Optionally you can set the url for your application or you can just finish it there.

Comment: thank you sir..what i was trying is importing the project it was so wrong..i am used to eclipse when using previous project all i do is import..thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this path when opening ?

Go to

`File->New Project->Select a Category->Pick one from Projects`.

Let's say PHP Application with Exciting Sources. Then select your project from the next window.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to work on a live site via FTP in NetBeans I would suggest using this NetBeans plugin:

Link:- http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer

**If you are working with local files:**

`File>New Project> PHP/HTML5 > PHP/HTML Application With Existing Sources.`

**If you are working with a GIT type repo:**

Create a proejct folder then initialize the repo and then pull from the repo you can also ADD/Commit/Push/Push via netbeans IDE toolbar.